# C# Overwrite specific text in .txt file

Tags: c#

So I'm actually working on a Class Library project (.dll). I was wondering how to select a specific part of a text file to be read and executed. In other words I mean:

**Is there any way to select a specific part that can overwrite the .dll file from the .txt file when this one is edited?**

```
if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            string[] config = new string[] {
                "Server website = \"\"",
                "\nServer rules = \"\"",
                "\nServer title = \"\"",
                "\nCredits = \"\"",
            };
            File.WriteAllLines(path, config);
```

This code block will create my .txt file in a specific path (`private string path = Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\scripts\StickyNotes.txt";`).

`\"\"` is the place where I wan't to add my own text that will overwrite.

An answer would be very welcome, thanks for taking your time

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Your title and code excerpt show that you're writing to a text file, but your bolded question says you want to read from a text file.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here: 1. `Overwrite specific text in .txt file` 2. `how to select a specific part of a text file to be read and executed` 3. `Is there any way to select a specific part that can overwrite the .dll file from the .txt file`. So which one is it?

Comment: Find the directory, iterate over the read item, and replace the found items.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, what I wan't is 1. Make a dll that will create a text file 2. Select specific text from a string so that it can be overwrited in the txt file

Answer (score 0):

The ways files work, you typically need to re-write the entire file. That's a limitation of most modern file systems for both Windows and linux, not the language or platform you're using.

You can sometimes get away with only writing a small section, but this only happens if the new text is exactly the same size as the old text. This is part of why fixed-length records are still often used for high-performance and large scale scenarios like relational databases.

While I'm here... the `File.Exists()` check is wasteful and useless. You should typically avoid using `File.Exists()` at all. Instead, use a `FileStream` with `FileMode.CreateNew` in conjunction with a `StreamWriter`. You'll need to handle the exception if creating the file fails, but you were supposed to do that anyway, because the file system is volatile relative to your code, and already existing is not the only reason you might fail to create a file.